# Open search results in a new window

Tags: search, master-page, search-results

I would like for the entire search results (stuff that appears after i type in a keyword and hit search) to appear in a new page. So far I haven't been able to get it to work correctly.

The only thing that I found so far is to replace the default search box with my own

```
    <table width="100%" style="float:right"><tr>
        <td width="99%"></td>
        <td  nowrap="nowrap">
        <input name="search" id="search" type="text" value ="Type keyword to search"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <Button class="btn_search" type="submit" style="background:clear" OnClick="javascript:window.open('http://plspf/sites/SearchCenter/Results.aspx?k='+search.value);return false;">
        <img alt="Search" border="0" height="16" src="/_layouts/images/search32x32.png" class="style1" /></Button>
        </td>                                     <td>

        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This works but eliminates the ability of the user to select scopes or change anything.
Is there a way to achieve the same result without modifying the master page?

Comment: Were you able to resolve?